# Can I pass variables into an ajax query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a website and I want to load different queries onto a page depending on which button is clicked.

Can I do it like this?

The HTML :

```
<div id="Proceed">
 4 Projects have been suggested to proceed.
</div>

<div id="result">
<!-- The title of the projects will be loaded here -->
</div>

<button id="foo"> Search </button>
```

The javascript:

```
$('#foo').on('click' function(){ //the button
    var x = $(this).find('div').attr('id'); // get the id
    $.ajax({
        url: 'profile/inbox',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { id: x },
        success: function(res){
             ('#result').html(res);
        }
    })
})
```

On profile.php:

```
function Inbox(){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `title` FROM `table` WHERE id=?",$id);
    $load = $query->result_array();
    $this->d['load'] = $load;
}
```

**EDIT**: I added some html to show where I plan to load the results of the query.

Comment: you can load and replace `html`, you have to use `POST` variable in `php` file.

Comment: you'd need to use `$id = $_POST['id'];` to get the `id` from your post request. Also ensure that your `url` is a valid `.php` file. See [this](https://thisinterestsme.com/simple-ajax-request-example-jquery-php/) article.

Comment: show us HTML code as well

Comment: @AbdullaNilam There you go.

Comment: <s>I guess you also need to send the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in order to receive as $_POST.</s> jQuery takes care of it.

Answer (score 0):

> For eg:(This is your code I just slightly modified because for
>   example)
>
> ```
> <div id="Proceed">
>    <select id="city" name="city">
>      <option value="">City:</option>
>      <option value="glasgow">Glasgow</option>
>      <option value="london">London</option>
>    </select>
> </div>
>
> <div id="result">
>  &nbsp;
> </div>
> <button id="foo"> Search </button>
> ```
>
> Script:(For eg:)
>
> ```
>   $("#foo").click(function() {                
>
>     $.ajax({    
>       url: 'profile/inbox',           //Pass this value to the corresponding URL
>       type: 'POST',             
>       dataType: "html",
>       data: {
>           "city": $('#city').val(),   //Here request the value for id name is city
>       },            
>       success: function(response){                    
>           $("#result").html(response);  //Retrieve value form URL to pass the view page and value to set in <div id="result">
>       }
>
>     });
>
> });
> ```
>
> This is my url page(you just see what are the process there.. This is
>   for eg)
>
> ```
>    $sql = "SELECT * FROM entries";
>    $result = $conn->query($sql);
>
>    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
>     // output data of each row
> 　　while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
>     　　echo "success"."id: " . $row["id"]. " - City: " . $row["city"]. "<br>";
>   　　}
>    } else {
> 　　echo "0 results";
>    }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

When you want to use a POST variable from PHP side you have to use 
`$_POST`/`$_REQUEST` method in your case `$id = $_POST['id'];` this will work